# No body rendered while returning contentresult in Episerver CMS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

I've problem with returning a contentResult in an Episerver 7 site. This problem only occur on the test-server while local environment works properly.

The code:

```
  public ActionResult Index(int statusCode, string message)
  {
     ... some unrelevant code.....
       return new ExtendedContentResult
            {
                StatusCode = 401,
                Content = MvcHtmlString.Create("Bananas test text").ToString(),
                ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                ContentType = "text/html",
                Headers = Response.Headers
            };
  }

public class ExtendedContentResult : ContentResult
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public NameValueCollection Headers { get; set; }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
        foreach (string s in Headers.Keys)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader(s, Headers[s]);
        }
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

The result differ on test versus dev. On the dev env. i get the expected result: 401 with "Bananas test text" written on the screen. BUT on the test-server i do get a 401, but i don't get any content on the  element.

What can be the cause of this behavior? What to check?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Solved. In web.config, i had initially set the custom-errors to mode=off:

What I had missed was also setting the globalErrorHandling-property in webconfig for Episerver to off, like:

Comment: Which version of IIS have you got on your dev and your test?  Also are they configured in the same way, i.e. both have the same modules installed?

Comment: IIS7, same on both. Though, the solution was setting globalErrorHandling-property in webconfig for Episerver to off.